# What grammatical function/part of speech is "to pay?"

Tags: parts-of-speech

What grammatical function/part of speech is "to pay" in the sentence below? Is it a verb?

> The package would provide large numbers of Americans with assistance to pay for healthcare.

Comment: I'm not convinced the cited example is syntactically valid. Certainly it's far more idiomatically expressed as *...with assistance **[in] paying** for healthcare.* But whichever verb form is used (infinitive or continuous participle), it's a (syntactically if not semantically *optional*) ***adverbial*** element - modifying the noun ***assistance***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I didn't know adverbs could modify nouns. I thought adverbs could only modify adjectives, adverbs, or verbs. And I thought only adjectives modify nouns.

Comment: This sentence above is poorly-written at best, word salad at worst. I'd look for a better example of what you want to find out.

Comment: I'm not really interested in trying to create a sharp dividing line between "adverb" and "adjective", but I suppose it's possible to say that the sequence ***to pay for healthcare*** adjectivally modifies the noun ***assistance*** - as would be the case if we preceded the noun by an obvious adjective ***immediate***. On the other hand, if we *follow* that noun with, say, ***tomorrow*** it looks to me like adverbial modification of the verb ***provide***. I could easily go with the idea that ***to pay for healthcare*** adverbially modifies ***provide*** in much the same way, but I don't know.